# Powershell Proxy setting

Tags: powershell, proxy, powershell-2.0

With this cmdlet can I check my proxy setting in powershell:

```
$regKey="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$proxyServer = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKey
$proxyServer | fl *proxy*
```

Or with this cmdlet:

```
Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' | Select-Object *Proxy*
```

My question is, how can I get the proxy settings for another network user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Enter-PsSession -Computername "nameofcomputer" | 
Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' | Select-Object *Proxy*
```

This however requires the WinRM service to be running on the target host.

If WinRM is not running it could be ran as a logon script with | Out-file "someplace\output.txt" then share that folder to get the data.

Comment: Alternatively this works as well:

`Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' | Select-Object *Proxy*`

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better with `Invoke-Command`. Getting objects and variables in a remote PSSession limit you to using those items in that session. You should do something like this:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "WkStn01"
$SB = {
    Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' `
        | Select-Object *Proxy*
}

$ProxySettings = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $SB
```

Finding out which computer a user is currently logged into is a bigger issue and would take a whole lot more effort so it would probably be best to know the name of the computer they are using.